# Convert from unit vector to rotation angles

Tags: rotations, robotics

In CAD model, the orientation can be represented by a unit vector $(i,j,k)$ where $i^2+j^2+k^2=1$.

In robot arm, the orientation can be represented by rotation angles $(rx,ry,rz)$ where each variable ranges from $-180^\circ \to 180^\circ$.

The axis directions have been aligned with respect to the world frame: $i$ is parallel to $x$, $j$ to $y$, $k$ to $z$. When $(i,j,k) = (0,0,1)$ then $(rx,ry,rz) = (0,0,0)$ which is pointing upwards (along $z$).

Suppose we rotate around y-axis for 90 degrees, i.e. $(rx,ry,rz) = (0,90,0)$, then $(i,j,k)$ becomes $(1,0,0)$ which is pointing along $x$.

The question is, in general, how to convert $(i,j,k)$ to $(rx,ry,rz)$, and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

you need to know 'rotation matrix' and 'roll, pitch, yaw'.

then you can understand below things.

source : http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html

So

*i = -sin(ry)*

*j = cos(ry)sin(rx)*

*k = cos(ry)cos(rx)*

its all.

simple :)

and vice versa,

*ry = - acsin(i)*

*rx = acsin(j/cos(ry))*

*rz = X*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Dear Minsu, Thank you very much for your kind help. I did some simulations of converting from i,j,k to rx,ry,rz and found that the orientation is **almost** correct but there is a consistent error which can be adjusted by $rz = 30^\circ$. I just wonder if something is missing in the above formulation?

Comment: Also, if we convert from $(rx,ry,rz)$ to $(i,j,k)$, if $rz$ is non-zero, the conversion only depending on $rx$ and $ry$ gives a wrong solution...

Comment: hmm.... ***rz*** can have no effect on z vector.

Think carefully about your standards.